# ¿Un consejo de buenas prácticas para ACTUALIZAR 50 registros o mas?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo 50 registros en una base de datos en mi proyecto Django , y me gustaría saber una mejor forma de actualizar cada registro en una sola consulta y NO en una consulta por cada registro para realizar la acción de actualización ,

```
Campos: id, valor, cantidad, codigo, descripcion.
```

Hasta el momento los tengo en bucle **for** obteniendo los datos ya guardados en un formulario a través de inputs list de la siguiente manera:

```
ids = request.POST.getlist('ids[]')
valores = request.POST.getlist('valores[]')
cantidades = request.POST.getlist('cantidad[]')
codigos = request.POST.getlist('codigos[]')
descripcion= request.POST.getlist('codigos[])

#Modelo = Datos

for id,val,cant,cod,desc in (ids, valores, cantidades, codigos, descripcion):
   check = Datos.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
   if check:
      Datos.objects.filter(pk=id).update(valor=val, cantidad=cant, codigo=cod, descripcion=desc)
```

Todos los registros ya han sido guardados, aquí los estoy actualizando con los inputs list de un formario básico en HTML, **como podría realizar esta acción sin realizar 50 consultas simultaneas** , sino realizar una sola consulta y actualizar todos los datos.

Comment: 50 registros no son nada de nada.. y las actualizaciones a bases de datos, la misma base de datos las hace de a una fila por vez. No hay una consuta masiva de actualizacion...

Comment: Cada vez que realizo esta operación, se me pone lento el sistema y se demora como un minuto recargando

Comment: y no podra venir por otro lado el problema?

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor y el bucle `for` si es el que pone lento el sistema, después de todo por cada iteracion se hacen 2 consultas SQL, una al obtener el registro y la segunda al actualizar dicho registro, siendo un total de **100 consultas SQL ejecutadas** por 50 registros, y mientras mas registros haya mas consultas habrá.

Entonces una solución seria utilizando el método [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) que actualiza de manera eficiente los campos dados en las instancias del modelo proporcionadas (generalmente con una consulta):

```
objs = []

for id, val, cant, cod, desc in (ids, valores, cantidades, codigos, descripcion):
    obj = Datos.objects.get(pk = id)
    obj.__init__(pk = obj.pk, valor = val, cantidad = cant, codigo = cod, descripcion = desc)
    
    objs.append(objs)

Datos.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['valor', 'cantidad', 'codigo', 'descripcion'])
```

De esta manera, para 50 registros, se ejecutarían 51 consultas SQL ya que en cada iteracion se obtiene un objeto, después se actualizan todos los objetos generalmente en una consulta, dando como resultado 51 consultas SQL ejecutadas.

Por otra parte, vi que verificabas que las instancias existieran, en dado caso exista la posibilidad de que un ID no pertenezca a ninguna instancia, tu código debería ser así:

```
objs = []

for id, val, cant, cod, desc in (ids, valores, cantidades, codigos, descripcion):
    obj = Datos.objects.filter(pk = id).first()

    if obj:
        obj.__init__(pk = obj.pk, valor = val, cantidad = cant, codigo = cod, descripcion = desc)
        objs.append(obj)

Datos.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['valor', 'cantidad', 'codigo', 'descripcion'])
```

---

Otra forma seria así:

```
for id, val, cant, cod, desc in (ids, valores, cantidades, codigos, descripcion):
    Datos.objects.filter(pk = id).update(
        valor = val, cantidad = cant, codigo = cod, descripcion = desc
    )
```

Donde solo se ejecutan 50 consultas SQL, específicamente de acuerdo al numero de registros.

Creo que esta es la mejor opción. Ademas no es necesario verificar si la instancia existe, pues si no se obtiene el objeto con el ID especificado no sucede ningún error y evidentemente no se actualiza ninguna instancia.

(intente encontrar una solución donde se puedan reducir mas las consultas SQL ejecutadas, pero nada... creo que solo hay estas dos maneras)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu colaboración , voy a intentar esta solución y te cuento.